# Resource id #7 error in exporting php to excel

Tags: php, excel, export-to-excel

In exporting PHP array to Excel document. i'm getting a error `Resource id #7` at last of the document. PHP Array   is

```
(       
    [0] => Array        
        (       
            [0] => Reg      
            [1] => Fname        
            [2] => Lname        
        )       

    [1] => Array        
        (       
            [0] => 63       
            [1] => Praveen      
            [2] => s        
        )       

    [2] => Array        
        (       
            [0] => 57       
            [1] => Prasad       
            [2] => K        
        )       

    [3] => Array        
        (       
            [0] => 456      
            [1] => Prabharan        
            [2] => G        
        )       

    [4] => Array        
        (       
            [0] => 080105306062     
            [1] => prasad       
            [2] => kppp     
        )       

)
```

and the output in the excel document is

```
Reg Fname   Lname
63  Praveen s
57  Prasad  K
456 Prabharan   G
80105306062 prasad  kppp
Resource id #7
```

the php code is:

```
 $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
            foreach ($list1 as $fields)
            {
                fputcsv($fp, $fields);
            }
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream'); 
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=export.csv');
            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
            header('Content-length:'.count($list1));
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
            header('Pragma: public');
            fclose($fp);
            die($fp);
```

Comment: `die($fp);`.... simply use `die();` because you're writing the output to `php://output` anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try use **ob_start()** and **ob_get_clean()**

```
ob_start();

$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');

//Your code to create CSV content
foreach ($list1 as $fields)
{
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=export.csv');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-length:'.count($list1));
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
fclose($fp);

//After file is created, make it output
die(ob_get_clean());
```